# How to redirect or load a website placed inside a WordPress directory?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I have a WordPress website hosted at the root folder and in the same root another CodeIgniter website placed in a folder.

The CodeIgniter site is not loading now. IT shows page not found error

The URL structure will be: http://website.com - wp site and http://website.com/wi/ver1/

which means I put the CodeIgniter site in a folder wi/ver1/.

The htaccess code for the base wp site is :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

# END WordPress

And the httaccess inside the wi/ver1 directory is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|js|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Could you please try to help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First of all check your `site_url` in wordpress project. Then change your `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]` because it contains double backward slashes in your `url` .

if you want to load your codeigniter site, change `base_url` in config.php file, add your folder name that `url`

For example :`$config['base_url'] =  http://yoursite.com/folder_name/`.

Comment: Site Address (URL) : is http://website.com and the code igniter sie url is http://website.com/wi/ver1 --> there is a wi folder and inside this folder ver1 folder which contains the CI files. I added the above change in WP htacces ,but no change. Ci is like this - $config['base_url'] = "http://website.com/wi/ver1/"

Comment: What error WP site shows when you go to  website.com

Comment: the website.com loads perfect. when we try the website.com/wi/ver1 it shows page not found, which is the 404 page of WP. The CI page is not loading..

Comment: What you want to do. Run both the sites, or only one site ?

Comment: If you want to run both the sites, then you have to create subdomain for CI application.

Comment: yes i want to run the both site. before it was working perfect.But today morning it suddenly stopped and showing the error.